# incongruent vs inconsistent vs nonconforming

Tags: comparisons

I am wondering which term would be the proper one to describe the problem.
We have data sets that are named according to a certain naming convention. What should I call those names that don't follow this convention by, for example, having a dash instead of an underscore, extra characters, etc.?
I feel like `incongruent` is more of an abstract term describing behavior for example. Are the names then `inconsistent`, `nonconforming`? Or is there another adjective to better describe it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nonconforming would work for me. But if everyone involved was aware of the naming conventions and didn't follow it, you could use noncompliant.

Here's how the California State Controller defines [noncompliant on its website](https://publicpay.ca.gov/Reports/UnavailableData.aspx?year=0&entitytypeid=1&rpt=2): "The public employer filed a compensation report that was incomplete, was in a format different than the one requested by the State Controller's Office, or was submitted after the reporting deadline and is currently in the review process.

Comment: That is a good another option, but in our case the discrepancy with the naming convention was caused by human error, rather than knowingly or intentionally.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest [atypical](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/atypical) as the most neutral.

> Dictionary: not typical; not conforming to the type; irregular; abnormal